# high cpu usage on search over lucene index

Tags: lucene, cpu-usage, jcr

I have a jcr repository (with embedded servlet container) which is using lucene for full text search. A search query seems to trigger a spike in cpu utilization which stays for quite some time even after the search results have returned. I took the thread dumps and realized that Lucene Merge thread was causing spike in cpu.

```
    "Lucene Merge Thread #0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005fd95000 nid=0x5add runnable [0x0000000049fc8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexOutput.writeVInt(IndexOutput.java:70)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsPositionsWriter.addPosition(FormatPostingsPositionsWriter.java:70)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.appendPostings(SegmentMerger.java:701)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTermInfos(SegmentMerger.java:635)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:573)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:156)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4443)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:4000)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:231)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:288)
```

And the behavior is very consistent. The search queries repeatedly seem to trigger merges (eventually slowing down the search itself)  which is hard for me to understand as to why search would trigger index merges.

The other related question is search queries get slower over a period of time. After a fresh restart of the server the lucene queries return in about 300-400ms but if the server has been running for a week, the same queries seem to take 3-4s or even more sometimes. I checked cpu & memory. The cpu usage is normal (under 1%) when the server is idle but a few searches send the cpu usage to 100% for quite some time (see above). The server has 12g of memory of which only 4g is currently being used(so no memory issues). Then why does the search get slower when server has been running for sometime (compared to a restart)?? Is it because slowly the cache is populated over time and a linear scan is being done over cache (but cache retrievals are supposed to be very fast - the very purpose of cache)
[EDITED]
Its CRX 2.3 which supports JCR 2.0 (JSR 283 specification). The repository has about 40k files roughly 15k of which are pdfs which are indexed for full text.

Comment: Could you perhaps add an example of what kind of queries you are performing against which JCR implementation?

Comment: Its CRX 2.3 which supports JCR 2.0 (JSR 283 specification). The repository has about 40k files roughly 15k of which are pdfs which are indexed for full text.

Comment: Could you add your Lucene searching and index code?

Answer (score 0):

Check your lucene connection after looking into lucene index. If it is not closed properly it would throw memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `SimpleFSDirectory` or `RAMDirectory`? Use `MMapDirectory`.

When we use `RAMDirectory` it loads whole index or large parts of it into “memory” that is virtual memory. As physical memory is limited, the operating system may, of course, decide to swap out our large `RAMDirectory`. So `RAMDirectory` is not a good idea to optimize index loading times.

On the other hand, if we don’t use `RAMDirectory` to buffer our index and use `NIOFSDirectory` or `SimpleFSDirectory`, we have to pay another price: Our code has to do a lot of syscalls to the O/S kernel to copy blocks of data between the disk or filesystem cache and our buffers residing in Java heap. This needs to be done on every search request, over and over again.

To resolve all above issue `MMapDirectory` uses virtual memory and a kernel feature called “mmap” to access the disk files.

Check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/use-lucene%E2%80%99s-mmapdirectory) also.

Comment: Could you edit your post to briefly explain the link? If the link dies in future then it will be harder to understand your answer.